# Find the value of $\int_0^1xf(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given:

$f(0)=0, f(1)=2, \text{ and} \int_0^1f(x)dx=3$

Find the value of $\int_0^1xf(x)dx$

Attempt:

Using partial integration.
$$
\int xf(x)dx=\frac{x^2f(x)}{2}-\int\frac{x^2f'(x)}{2}dx
$$
Maybe I'm choosing the wrong $u$ and $v$. Then I tried to swap $u$ and $v$.
$$
\int xf(x)dx=xF(x)-\int F(x)dx
$$

Comment: @Cristoph, doesn't seem to help.

Comment: As you have written the problem, it cannot be solved, unless you know something more about function $f$, like to what class of functions it belongs to. Otherwise, it would be solvable if you were given $F(1)$ and $\int_0^1 F(x)dx$ or if you were to calculate $\int_0^1 xf'(x)dx$.

Comment: Another example: for any $a$ the function $f(x) = (2 a -24)x^3 + (24-3 a) x^2+(a+2) x$ has $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) =2$ and $\int_0^1 f(x){\rm d}x = 3$. However $\int_0^1 xf(x){\rm d}x = \frac{112 - a}{60}$ can be anything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single answer to this problem. Consider
$$ f_1(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0 & \text{for }x=0\\ 3 &\text{for }0<x<1\\ 2&\text{for }x=1 \end{array} \right. $$
and 
$$ f_2(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 6x & \text{for }0\le x<1\\ 2 &\text{for }x=1 \end{array} \right. $$
They both satisfy your conditions, but
$$ \int_0^1 xf_1(x) dx = \frac32$$
$$ \int_0^1 xf_2(x) dx = 2$$
By choosing other functions, you can get any result you want. You can even limit yourself to continuous differentiable functions, and it's still true.